# Showing results for an non-matching string in Google Maps API Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

A client wanted to have the ability for users to input garbled text or incorrect text into the autocomplete dropdown, and for it to show the last correct match (instead of emptying the dropdown, as is default). Similarly, the normal autocomplete function would need to restart when user deletes the characters breaking it.

Which event handler should one attach the function that will check how many new results have been returned? Options could be 'keyup' on the input element, but it happens before results return; another option is on the resizing of the ".pac-container" element (via [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)). I didn't see any handy "result-returned" event on the Autocomplete.

Once the basic replacement is working and the events are firing in order, then there are more problems on deletion of characters. Somehow, extra results are getting stuck on the div in the wrong cases. [Example JSBin when one gets to this point.](https://jsbin.com/tonape/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final JSBin solution can be seen [here](https://jsbin.com/qixejij/1/edit?html,output).

Some explanation:

- Essentially, this gets the last successful state and re-applies it until there is a successful state again.
- I chose to setTimeout on the keyup event, since using MutationObserver was triggering too unreliably and too many times and made it hard to store and return to old states
- Needed to add classes to added results, so I could manipulate new and old results in the dropdown
- A rather complex set of conditions needed to be established to cause this to not break on deletion and actually remove the right elements in different cases. These cases roughly correspond with:

  - no result and last time succeeded,
  - no result and last time failed,
  - some result and last time failed,
  - some result and last time succeeded
- Including a function to force remove the dropdown if user clicks off

These can be seen in the JSBin at work. I hope this helps somebody along the way!